# Confused by "mean" and "median" of $\alpha$ parameter in Lognormal Distribution

Tags: lognormal-distribution, parameterization

I read a book and find the following content (Fig.1). It is about lognormal distribution. What confused me is in the red box.

In Fig.1, $\alpha$ is said "the mean of $z$ on the log scale". Then I suppose the equation is:

$\alpha = mean(log(z))=\frac{1}{n} \cdot \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{log(z_i)}} $

However, the equation is:

$\alpha = log(median(z))$

Why the equation is not in accordance with the narration?
[image: Fig.1]

Comment: The table doesn't posit the existence of any data "$z_i$:" it concerns the mathematical properties of *distributions.*  In this context, the mean of the random variable $z$ is its expectation.

Comment: @whuber I'm still confused that $mean(log(z))$ is not the same as $log(median(z))$, because the first is "mean", while the second is "median".

Comment: Because (by definition) $\log(z)$ has a Normal distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta,$ its mean is $\alpha.$ Because all Normal distributions are symmetrical, $\alpha$ is also the median of $\log(z).$  Because the logarithm is a monotonically increasing function, the log of the median is the median of the log (no matter what distribution $z$ might have).

Comment: @whuberThanks so much! Now I understand.